# How to remove funny characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding

On the following line:

```
alert ( "Apenas os números 0, 1, 3, 5, 7 e 9 são permitidos." );
```

it prints like this:

```
Apenas os n?meros 0, 1, 3, 5, 7 e 9 s?o permitidos.
```

The problem is that the characters **ú** and **ã** are not showing correctly.

In HTML I did something like:

```
Apenas os n&uacute;meros 0, 1, 3, 5, 7 e 9 s&atilde;o permitidos.
```

and it worked, but I don't know what to do in JavaScript. What should I do to solve this?
If it has anything to do with the problem i'm using UTF-8.

Thanks and sorry about the English.

Comment: are you sure that declared encoding matches actual encoding?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. There is charset=UTF-8 written in the meta tag in the head of my HTML file. I assume this is the declared encoding so what do you mean by actual encoding?

Comment: [@StudioWorks: ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/429583/studioworks) In Firefox goto Tools>Page Info and see what the Encoding says there. Meta tags are seldomly(if ever) used, the real encoding is in the HTTP header. Other than that, I'm not sure how to test without knowing the actual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript always prints in UTF-16 no matter what the HTML is set to, try to find the hex decimal values of those characters.

Then show them like this:

```
\uXXXX
```

Where XXXX are the 2 hexavalues of the character.

For example:

```
alert("\u05D0");
```

Comment: God, I love this site. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, I just signed up, I quite like it too ^^